# Sums of sets in ${[n] \choose k}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose we look at all sets in ${[n] \choose k}$, for some $k \leq n/2$, and  place them in layers according to the sum of their elements. Then, we say that two sets $A$ and $B$ from consecutive layers are connected by an edge, if there is some $i \in [n-1]$ for which $(i,i+1)A = B$. That is, if $A \Delta B = \{i,i+1\}$. Is it true that any two consecutive layers have a perfect matching, in the sense that all the elements of the layer with less sets are matched? For instance, let's take $n=6$, $k=3$. And let's match the layer with sum $12$ to the layer with sum $11$:

$(\{6,5,1\}, \{6,4,1\}), (\{6,4,2\},\{6,3,2\}), (\{5,4,3\}, \{5,4,2\})$.

Comment: sum 13 only has 6,5,2 and 6,4,3

Comment: Yes, The goal is to match all sets of the layer with fewer sets. So, for instance, we can match all sets with sum $13$ to sets with sum $12$ like this: $(\{6,5,2\},\{6,5,1\}), (\{6,4,3\},\{5,4,3\})$.

Comment: I feel like you ought to be able to do some sort of induction on $n$.  Idea: first match all the things with max element at most $n-1$.  Then look at the things with max element $n$, and try to match these together (they look like sets with max element at most $n-1$ and with sum $n$ less than originally).  The only problem here is that we need to preserve which layer has more elements in each of these, which in general doesn't even happen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking at two consecutive ranks of the poset denoted
$L(k,n-k)$. I proved the existence of a matching in
http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/42.pdf. A more elementary
proof based on linear algebra was later given by R. A. Proctor,
*Amer. Math. Monthly* **89** (1982), 721-734. Another elementary proof
based on linear algebra appears in my book *Algebraic Combinatorics*
(built into the proof of Corollary 6.10). It is an open problem to
find a combinatorial proof.

Comment: Professor Stanley, I always thoroughly appreciate your contributions to this website [and of course to the development and exposition of combinatorics as a whole].  Just wanted to say thanks!  --a current student of Jeff Kahn

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea this problem was studied before.